# Cannot insert the data into the table using C# visual studio 2008

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, connection

hello every i was trying to create simple student form n add the data to the database but coudlnt do this, there was no error during the execution of the program, application executes nicely but no changes in the table, n the values are nt inserted into the table, what might b the problem plz suggest me, im writing my code below..
thanq in advance :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace School.Project
{

class Student
{
    public static string constr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings"SchoolConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    public static int AddStudent(string title, string fname, string lname, string fathername, string gender, string clas, string sec, int age, string dob, string religion, string caste, string image, string address, string homeno, string cell, string email)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        con.Open();
        SqlTransaction t = con.BeginTransaction();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Student (Title,FirstName,LastName,FatherName,Gender,Class,Section,Age,DateOfBirth,Religion,Caste,Image,Address,HomePhone,CellPhone,Email) VALUES(@Title,@FirstName,@LastName,@FatherName,@Gender,@Class,@Section,@Age,@DateOFBirth,@Religion,@Caste,@Image,@Address,@HomePhone,@CellPhone,@Email)",con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", title);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FirstName", fname);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("LastName", lname);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FatherName", fathername);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", gender);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Class", clas);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", sec);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Age", age);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DateOfBirth", dob);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Religion", religion);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Caste", caste);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Image", image);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Address", address);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HomePhone", homeno);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CellPhone", cell);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", email);
        cmd.Transaction = t;

        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        t.Commit();
        con.Close();
        return i;
    }

    private void btSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string title = cbTitle.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string fname = txtfname.Text;
        string lname = txtlname.Text;
        string fathername = txtfatherName.Text;
        string gender = cbGender.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string clas = cbClass.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string section = cbSection.SelectedItem.ToString();
        int age = int.Parse(txtAge.Text);
        string dob = txtdob.Text;
        string religion = txtReligion.Text;
        string caste = txtCaste.Text;
        string imagepath = txtpath.Text;
        string address = txtAddress.Text;
        string homeno = txtHome.Text;
        string cell = txtCell.Text;
        string email = txtEMail.Text;

        int i = Project.Student.AddStudent(title, fname, lname, fathername, gender, clas, section, age, dob, religion, caste, imagepath, address, homeno, cell, email);
        if (i == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Student Added Succesfully, Thanq", "Inserted", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            ClearAll();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Couldnt enter the data", "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: is there a reason why some of your parameters have @ and some don't?

Answer (score 3):

add a bracket `[ ]` on some fields of your query because some of the are reserved words:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("
INSERT INTO Student ([Title],FirstName,LastName,
                      FatherName,Gender,
                      [Class],Section,Age,DateOfBirth,
                      Religion,Caste,[Image],Address,
                      HomePhone,CellPhone,Email)             
VALUES(@Title,@FirstName,@LastName,
       @FatherName,@Gender,@Class,@Section,
       @Age,@DateOFBirth,@Religion,@Caste,
       @Image,@Address,@HomePhone,
       @CellPhone,@Email)",con);
```

> [Title]
>
> [Image]

**UPDATED 1**

Instead of `SqlTransaction t = con.BeginTransaction();`

try this:

`SqlTransaction t = con.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)`

[Source: Use database transactions](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_db_transaction.html)

Comment: no solution brother i have corrected my code though, the program is running and executing nicely but the values are nt inserted into the table

Comment: tried this one 
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Student ([Title],[FirstName],[LastName],[FatherName],[Gender],[Class],[Section],[Age],[DateOfBirth],[Religion],[Caste],[Image],[Address],[HomePhone],[CellPhone],[Email]) VALUES(@Title,@FirstName,@LastName,@FatherName,@Gender,@Class,@Section,@Age,@DateOFBirth,@Religion,@Caste,@Image,@Address,@HomePhone,@CellPhone,@Email)",con);

Comment: how about this? `SqlTransaction t = con.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)`

Comment: yeah trid it but im nt able to find out the solution :((

Answer (score 2):

Some of your parameters contain the "@" symbol and some don't....

Comment: no solution brother i have corrected my code though, the program is running and executing nicely but the values are nt inserted into the table

Comment: Goto SQL Server Management Studio and in your database execute:     SELECT DB_ID()

Run the profiler against this database id and see if any activity is going on at the server level.

Comment: im trying this one with sql server provided by visual studio inbuilt, im nt using management studio...

Answer (score 1):

1.) don't pass so many parameters. You want to add a STUDENT, that should ring all your bells. Pass only one parameter - class Student populated with the values you want.

2.) I don't think a transaction is necessary here. You want to push only one object, so if it fails, the result is the same - no changes done.

3.) as Daren said, you don't have properly written parameters in your query

EDIT:
Just tried the simplified version and it works like a charm... Here's the code:

Page.aspx.cs

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);

        }

        void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Student student = new Student() { Id = 1, Name = "John" };
            int rowsAffected = Student.AddStudent(student);

            Response.Write(rowsAffected);
        }
    }


    public class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public static int AddStudent(Student s)
        {
            string conString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["string1"].ConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
            {
                con.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Students (Name) VALUES (@Name)", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", s.Name);
                return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

Please, try to modify it to suit your needs and let me know, if it finally works. It has some problems (like not putting the class Student in a separate file), but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: yeah tried with the less parameters n i have corrected the query too, but the same result :(,i have to enter the details into table manually from solution explorer its not taking the values from the form,

Comment: @mujahid, does your function return any errors or something? What output do you get? Do you supply ALL mandatory values into your table?

Comment: the function Addstudent() return integer value, im nt getting any errors program is running succesfullly but i couldnt see the inserted values into the table

Comment: @mujahid, ok, that's just weird... Try to debug your app line by line. That should give us a clue what went wrong. I bet there's something so obvious that no one checks for it...